# Excel Spreadsheets: If A:A does not equal C:C, how do i list columns A, B and C somewhere else?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have an issue with referencing an excel spreadsheet:

I have data in columns A and C that's (mostly) equal, I want to isolate and create a separate list for the rows that are not equal.

For example, I have :

```
             A                B                C
    1-    5 John Lane     Joe Bloggs      5 John Lane
    2-    6 John Lane     Mary Lamb       35 Woopwoop Court
```

For the rows where A and C are equal, for this particular exercise, I don't care about. The rows where A and C are not equal, (row 2 above) I would like to compile a list of these, somewhere else.

I began with `=IF(a:a<>c:c,c:c=f:f,f:f=0)` 
This should have returned as column f (otherwise blank) returning either a value of 0 or of the contents of column c for that particular row, it didn't and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

I would like to end up with a truncated list of all rows (columns A, B and C) in a separate worksheet for where A and C are not equal so I can list those properties where the owners live somewhere else.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to achive this would be appreciated

Comment: basic idea `=IF(A1=C1, 1,0)` use this down Colum D and then use filter to identify it. note: in this statment if A* is equal to C* it will display 1 if not equal it will display 0

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, how would I then take that list of 1s and 0s as a reference and copy all the data from each column somewhere else?

Comment: My suggestion was to use row 1 as a filter http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073941.aspx or you could do what @TDrabas has said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this.

In your cell F2 (I'm assuming your row 1 is a header) type `=IF(A2=C2,0,C2)`. Then drag this down by using this tiny square located in bottom-right corner of the cell F2. You should see 0s and values from the column C populating column F.

All you have to do right now is to copy the contents of column F, paste special (Ctrl+Alt+V) as values, and sort.

Hope this answers your question.